# Certain Pods not downloading after 'pod install'

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I'm using the M1 MacBook and I just updated my repository from git (which was working fine) and suddenly I'm getting **module not found** errors.

After digging deeper, I noticed that some modules (like Google Places & FirebaseAnalytics) were in fact not being downloaded.

Podfile:

[image: Only Support Files]

```
    # platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
target 'app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for app

  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Applio'
  pod 'SQLite.swift'
  pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar'
  pod 'iOSDropDown'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod "BSImagePicker", "~> 3.1"
  pod "StompClientLib"
  # Pods for app
  
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.2.5'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.3.5'
    pod 'RangeSeekSlider', '~> 1.8.0'
 
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.12.5'
    pod 'PureLayout', '~> 3.1.9'
    pod 'TagListView', :git => 'https://github.com/govindravaliya/TagListView.git', :branch => 'master'
    
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.1'
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
             end
        end
     end

end
```

Please help.

Comment: Look at the output of running `pod install`. Does it show the expected output for the missing pods? Are you really using iOS 9?

Comment: @HangarRash the pod output seems fine… it says all pods installed. Should I post a verbose output? Also, iOS 9 line is commented.

Comment: A number of those podfiles are outdated. For example **pod Firebase/Analytics'** is supposed to be **pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'** and **pod 'Firebase/Messaging'** is supposed to be **pod 'FirebaseMessaging'** . Also note that *For apps that use CocoaPods, the Firebase pod is deprecated in v9.0 and higher*. A number of others need to be updated as well. Also, ensure you have the latest cocoapods installed and `pod repo update`.

Comment: @Jay Thanks Jay for the input. I'll update the pods, however, pods like GooglePlaces are up to date as per my knowledge. Why is it only downloading a dummy.h file and not the import files?

Comment: Oh, just noticed the RealmSwift is outdated as well. Use **pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'**.

Comment: As a test, I would create a new project, copy that podfile to it's folder, and comment out `# source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` and all the lines from the `post_install` down and then `pod install` on the new project and see what the results are. (obviously change the target to the test project). That will eliminate some variables and you can tweak it until correct so you don't have to alter your main project until it works correctly. There may also be a trunk issue so you may need to `pod repo remove trunk` as well.

Comment: @Jay Tried making a test project with the same podfile and ran pod install. All the pods got installed except for the same ones that weren't working for the original project. It's weird how it only happens with Pods like GooglePlaces, FirebaseAnalytics and SendbirdChatSDK. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just crafted a small project and built a podfile that included *FirebaseAnalytics* as well as Firestore as shown in the [Install Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#cocoapods). I did a pod install and it installed and the project ran. Obviously there's a difference in our environments - I am on macOS 14.2.1, XCode 15.2 and Cocoapods 1.14.3 (pod --version to get that). It installed all of the current releasees for Firebase 10.21.0 as well as GoogleSignIn (7.0.0) etc. So the issue sounds environmental more than anything.

Comment: @Jay Got it. I’m really unable to narrow it down though, it used to work and after I changed the branch that I was working in, I started facing this issue even after reverting back. I’m on XCode 15 as well, latest macOS Cocoapods 1.15.0

Comment: @Jay Finally got it to work by uninstalling cocoapods and reinstalling it again. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. It was as trivial as uninstalling and re-installing Cocoapods:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

And then re-installing it:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Finally:

```
pod install
```